# Creating windowed materialized view in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, aggregate, window-functions, clickhouse, materialized-views

Events from a MQTT server are inserted into this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mqtt_float( 
    topic   LowCardinality( String ) NOT NULL                     ,
    ts      DateTime64(2,'Europe/Paris') NOT NULL DEFAULT now()   ,
    value   Float64 NOT NULL                                      ,
)   ENGINE=ReplacingMergeTree -- eliminates duplicates with same (topic,ts) which should not occur
    ORDER BY (topic,ts)
    PRIMARY KEY (topic,ts);
```

Rows contain sensor data, topic is the name of a sensor, ts is the timestamp, and value is what was measured by the sensor at this time. To speed things up when plotting data over long periods of time, I have created a materialized view to summarize per minute. This works well:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mqtt_float_minute
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (topic, ts)
POPULATE
AS SELECT
    topic,
    toStartOfMinute(ts) AS ts,
    avg(value)          AS favg,
    min(value)          AS fmin,
    max(value)          AS fmax
FROM mqtt_float
GROUP BY topic,ts;
```

Now I want to learn how to use the [Window View](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view/#window-view-experimental) feature, which supposedly does the same thing in a more efficient manner. Here's my attempt:

```
CREATE WINDOW VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mqtt_float_minute_w
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (topic, ts)
POPULATE
AS SELECT
    topic,
    toStartOfMinute(ts) AS ts,
    avg(value) OVER window1   AS favg,
    min(value) OVER window1   AS fmin,
    max(value) OVER window1   AS fmax
FROM mqtt_float
WHERE is_int=0
GROUP BY topic,ts
WINDOW window1 AS (PARTITION BY topic, toStartOfMinute(ts));
```

It fails:

Received exception from server (version 22.12.3):
Code: 215. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Column `value` is not under aggregate function and not in GROUP BY. Have columns: ['toStartOfMinute(ts)','topic']: While processing topic, toStartOfMinute(ts) AS ts, avg(value) OVER window1 AS favg, min(value) OVER window1 AS fmin, max(value) OVER window1 AS fmax. (NOT_AN_AGGREGATE)

I'm quite puzzled by this error message. Any ideas how to make it work?

The WINDOW clause seems mandatory for a window view, which makes sense. Basically what I want is to compute the aggregates of column value, grouping by (topic,toStartOfMinute(ts)). When the current minute window closes, there will be no more records inserted with timestamps belonging to that window, so the point of this type of view is: clickhouse can discard the aggregation states which will never be used again, and save some storage.

Comment: Is it possible that `value` is a keyword and that causes the problem?

Comment: @LajosArpad it works fine in all other tables as a column name so I don't think it's a keyword (the plural "values" is)